# Docker integration in OpenShift

Tags: docker, boot2docker, openshift-origin

I came to know about Docker concept which seems very interesting.
I have installed Docker on my windows machine using boot2docker, which works as expected.

I have seen many blogs which talks about docker support in OpenShift, wanted to know how well it supports and what are the ways this can be integrated in OpenShift origin/enterprise or online.

In online I am not sure whether it works. Please provide me with details.

it will be really helpful.

Thanks,
yash

Comment: See: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/geard-the-intersection-of-paas-docker-and-project-atomic

Answer (score 0):

The best explanation so far is here https://www.openshift.com/blogs/openshift-v3-platform-combines-docker-kubernetes-atomic-and-more. I'd try to sum it up here in the answer but the article does a better job.